# "Enable Always on support..." for SSIS through C# or powershell

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, ssis, alwayson

I would like turn on Always on support for SSIS.  I am able to do this using the UI (Right click on Integration Services Catalogs, click "Enable always on Support").  I would like to see if there is a way to do this in power shell or C# using [microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices?view=sqlserver-2017)

This is the UI for Enable always on support

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Powershell solution**

First to enable always on availability groups feature on an instance you can use:

```
Enable-SqlAlwaysOn -Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\Computer\Instance
```

- [Enable or Disable Always On availability group feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/enable-and-disable-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Enable-SqlAlwaysOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/enable-sqlalwayson?view=sqlserver-ps)

Then you should create an Always on availability group and add the SSISDB database to this group:

- [Create an Always On availability group using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-an-availability-group-sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-2017) *(with examples)*
- [Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/add-sqlavailabilitydatabase?view=sqlserver-ps)

From the links above, you should follow these steps:

> 1. Change directory (cd) to the server instance that is to host the primary replica.
> 2. Create an in-memory availability-replica object for the primary replica.
> 3. Create an in-memory availability-replica object for each of the secondary replicas.
> 4. Create the availability group.
> 5. Join the new secondary replica to the availability group
> 6. For each database in the availability group, create a secondary database by restoring recent backups of the primary database, using
>      RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY.
> 7. Join every new secondary database to the availability group.
> 8. Optionally, use the Windows dir command to verify the contents of the new availability group.

*Example provided in the link above*

```
# Backup my database and its log on the primary  
Backup-SqlDatabase `  
    -Database "SSISDB" `  
    -BackupFile "\\share\backups\SSISDB.bak" `  
    -ServerInstance "PrimaryComputer\Instance"  

Backup-SqlDatabase `  
    -Database "SSISDB" `  
    -BackupFile "\\share\backups\SSISDB.log" `  
    -ServerInstance "PrimaryComputer\Instance" `  
    -BackupAction Log   

# Restore the database and log on the secondary (using NO RECOVERY)  
Restore-SqlDatabase `  
    -Database "SSISDB" `  
    -BackupFile "\\share\backups\SSISDB.bak" `  
    -ServerInstance "SecondaryComputer\Instance" `  
    -NoRecovery  

Restore-SqlDatabase `  
    -Database "SSISDB" `  
    -BackupFile "\\share\backups\SSISDB.log" `  
    -ServerInstance "SecondaryComputer\Instance" `  
    -RestoreAction Log `  
    -NoRecovery  

# Create an in-memory representation of the primary replica.  
$primaryReplica = New-SqlAvailabilityReplica `  
    -Name "PrimaryComputer\Instance" `  
    -EndpointURL "TCP://PrimaryComputer.domain.com:5022" `  
    -AvailabilityMode "SynchronousCommit" `  
    -FailoverMode "Automatic" `  
    -Version 12 `  
    -AsTemplate  

# Create an in-memory representation of the secondary replica.  
$secondaryReplica = New-SqlAvailabilityReplica `  
    -Name "SecondaryComputer\Instance" `  
    -EndpointURL "TCP://SecondaryComputer.domain.com:5022" `  
    -AvailabilityMode "SynchronousCommit" `  
    -FailoverMode "Automatic" `  
    -Version 12 `  
    -AsTemplate  

# Create the availability group  
New-SqlAvailabilityGroup `  
    -Name "MyAG" `  
    -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\PrimaryComputer\Instance" `  
    -AvailabilityReplica @($primaryReplica,$secondaryReplica) `  
    -Database "SSISDB"  

# Join the secondary replica to the availability group.  
Join-SqlAvailabilityGroup -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\SecondaryComputer\Instance" -Name "MyAG"  

# Join the secondary database to the availability group.  
Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\SecondaryComputer\Instance\AvailabilityGroups\MyAG" -Database "SSISDB"
```

Comment: you have explained about adding the catalog db to alway on AG.  But after doing that there is another option which enables ssis support for always on.
I think it corresponds to [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.catalog.configurealwaysonsupport?view=sqlserver-2017#Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_IntegrationServices_Catalog_ConfigureAlwaysOnSupport_System_Collections_Generic_List_Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_IntegrationServices_ReplicaDataInfo__]
I dont know how to use it tho

Comment: @SumitSingh when you click on the enable support command it will open add database to AG wizard

Comment: exactly, but I don't want to use the UI to do that. I want to do it in .net or powershell.

Comment: @SumitSingh if you agree with that. Then the answer provided can do what you are looking for